# PHP Почему насчитывает лишнее время?

Tags: php, время

```
date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime ("25-08-2011 17:31:17")-strtotime ("25-08-2011 17:30:30"));
```

Вывод 1970-01-01 03:00:47
Почему так? должно же быть 0000-00-00 00:00:47

Comment: Потому что datetime отсчитывается от 1 января 70-го года прошлого века. И плюс 3 часа зоны времени.

Comment: Вы можете получить разницу между датами используя функцию  mktime
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mktime.php
Например, в вашем случае разница в 47 секунд получится из следующего выражения: mktime(17, 31, 17, 8, 25, 2011) - mktime(17, 30, 30, 8, 25, 2011);

Comment: Он добавляет смещение вашей временной зоны (+3) часа

Comment: `этот диапазон был ограничен датами 01-01-1970 до 19-01-2038.` - поверьте - это было не сложно [открыть крутануть и почитать](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php)

Comment: выполнил ваш код из вопроса, получил `1970-01-01 00:00:47`

Comment: `date` - вам  это сделать не сможет. Так как настроена по календарю, а так-как, все это, начало работать с 1970 года, приказать ей дать нам `00 00 0000 00:00:47` мы не можем. Чтобы это сделать, вам нужно отдельно писать функцию.